# SQL database query issue

Tags: python, sqlite

As part of a coding project I am doing, I have to create a program that will sort folders into 8 filing cabinets which have 3 shelves each organised in alphabetical order based on the surname (A,A,AB,  BC,C,D,  E,F,G,  HIJ,L,M,  M,M,MN,  O,PQ,R, RS,S,S,  T,UVW,WXYZ). The problem I am having is with a function I am writing so that I can call it at any point and input the details of the student and find out where the folder should be placed (which cabinet?, which shelf?, which position?)

What I have so far finds all entries in the database with a similar surname and then sort it into alphabetical order to find out where the new folder should go relative to all folders with a similar surname.

```
    import sqlite3
cabinets = ["A","A","AB", "BC","C","D", "E","F","G", "HIJ","L","M", "M","M","MN", "O","PQ","R", "RS","S","S", "T","UVW","WXYZ"]
def location(forename,secondname):
    cabinet = ""
    shelf = ""
    position = ""
    if secondname != "" and forename != "":
        firstletter = (secondname[:(len(secondname) - (len(secondname)-1))]).lower()
        cursor = db.execute("SELECT * FROM Folders WHERE Surname LIKE ?", (firstletter + "%",))
        shelfinventory = []
        for row in cursor:
            shelfinventory.append((row[2]).lower())
        shelfinventory = sorted(shelfinventory)
        shelfposition = shelfinventory.index(secondname.lower())

        position = [cabinet, shelf, shelfposition]
        return position

db = sqlite3.connect("databasetest.db")
conn = db.cursor() 
db.execute('''CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Folders
             (StudentID INT PRIMARY KEY, Forename TEXT, Surname TEXT)''')

db.execute("INSERT INTO Folders VALUES (?, ?, ?);", ("1", "Ben", "Smath"))
db.execute("INSERT INTO Folders VALUES (?, ?, ?);", ("2", "John", "Smith"))
db.execute("INSERT INTO Folders VALUES (?, ?, ?);", ("3", "Debra", "Swith"))
db.execute("INSERT INTO Folders VALUES (?, ?, ?);", ("4", "Simon", "Stith"))

print(location("Debra", "Swith"))
```

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Please check that the code excerpt in your question is properly indented! Whitespace is significant in Python.

Comment: Also, please read the [how to create a MCVE](/help/mcve)

Comment: What data do you have? what are the constrains?

Comment: Right now I only have to create a program that would work with any name that is inputted and the only constrains are the filing cabinet layout and how they are organised